# Converting dict of two dict into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api, dictionary

Using an API, I am getting a dict which is inside 2 dicts and I want to convert this data to pandas df. My target columns in df are ['technology', 'version', 'release']

```
json_data = r.json()
print(json_data)
>> {'data': {'InfoMD': [{'id': '1', 'technology': 'LTE', 'version': '878', 'release': 'LTEA'}, 
{'id': '2', 'technology': '2G', 'version': '2G 60, 'release': '2GA'}, 
{'id': '3', 'technology': '5G', 'version': '5G_07', 'release': '5GA '}, 
{'id': '4', 'technology': 'LTE', 'version': 'LTEP8', 'release': 'LTER '}, 
{'id': '5', 'technology': '2G', 'version': '2G_60, 'release': '5GB '}, 
{'id': '6', 'technology': '5G', 'version': '5G_07', 'release': '5GB'}}}
```

Comment: ``import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame(json_data['data']['InfoMD'])``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict =  {'data': {'InfoMD': [{'id': '1', 'technology': 'LTE', 'version': '878', 
'release': 'LTEA'}, 
{'id': '2', 'technology': '2G', 'version': '2G 60', 'release': '2GA'}, 
{'id': '3', 'technology': '5G', 'version': '5G_07', 'release': '5GA '}, 
{'id': '4', 'technology': 'LTE', 'version': 'LTEP8', 'release': 'LTER '}, 
{'id': '5', 'technology': '2G', 'version': '2G_60', 'release': '5GB '}, 
{'id': '6', 'technology': '5G', 'version': '5G_07', 'release': '5GB'}]}}

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(dict['data']['InfoMD']).drop(['id'], axis = 1)
# drop() is used to remove 'id' column
```